# Linker error: Undefined reference to Class::enum

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have an enum as a class member in `MyClass`:

```
.h file:

private:
enum pattern { PAT_ZERO, PAT_SEQ, PAT_PIPE };
static enum pattern pattern;
```

I use it in a function:

```
.cpp file:

int MyClass::function(){
    switch (pattern) {
       case PAT_ZERO:
         break;
```

It compiles, but I get a linker  error.

```
 In function `MyClass::function()':
MyClass.cpp:(.text._ZN12MyClass11functionEP6threadPvj+0x120): undefined reference to `MyClass::pattern'
```

I can't seem to figure out why it's an "undefined reference".

Comment: Static class member variables are only *declared* in the class, they have to be *defined* as well. There are thousands of duplicates here on SO, do some searching.

Answer (score 3):

Static data members usually need a *definition*, as well as the *declaration* in the class, so add one to the source file:

```
enum MyClass::pattern MyClass::pattern = PAT_ZERO;
```

The initialiser is optional - it will be zero-initialised (i.e. initialised to `PAT_ZERO`) if you leave it out.